# Getting the width and height of image file stored on AWS S3 Bucket in Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing a Web Application using Laravel. I am storing all the image files on the AWS S3 Bucket. Now, I like to get the width and height of the image file stored on s3. But, I store all the image files as private so that I cannot access them from the s3 url. In my code, I download the image file from s3 like this

```
file = Storage::disk('s3')->get($s3_file_name);
```

If I want to display the image in the browser, I return the image in the action method like this.

```
return response($file)->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
```

But I like to get the width and height of image after I download from the s3 like this.

```
file = Storage::disk('s3')->get($s3_file_name);
```

How can I get it?

I cannot use getimagesize(filename) since I am storing the file as private on the s3 Bucket.

Comment: So what object is in `$file` variable after you get it from s3?

Answer (score 1):

S3 will not calculate dimensions for you. You calculate them beforehand anyway.

You can use user-defined meta tags. You can set them in when you send the object, or update them after they exist.

For private objects, the API must return user-defined meta tags.

For public objects, you can use the traditional GET verb or just the http HEAD verb in the object's public url.

Even javascript + ajax can read this header information.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a lambda function that gets triggered when you upload an image, calculates dimensions and store results in a dynamodb table automatically, then you can reference the result stored in dynamodb table with your laravel code.

It's quite easy to do with python:

```
from PIL import Image
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(
            event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')

    local = '/tmp/'+key
    s3.download_file(bucket,key, local)
    im = Image.open(local)

    width, height = im.size

    dynamodb.put_item(
        TableName='dimension',
        Item={
           'keyname': {'S': key},
           'height': {'N': height},
           'width': {'N': width}
            })
```

**Prerequisites:**

1.Don't forget to make a dynamodb table first named *dimension* and *keyname* as primary key

2. As PIL or PILLOW is not a standard python libary found in lambda environment, you have to make a custom deploment package and here is how you will do it :
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python